# Why I am getting - error unauthorized when deploying Parse Platform and Back4App Problem

Tags: parsing, back4app

I wrote an ionic angular app by using parse platform. Successfully installed in a local environment and connected to my back4app account by properly initializing appID and javascriptID

```
const Parse = require('parse');
Parse.initialize("appID", "jsID");
Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';
```

When I run application locally, it works well by connecting to remote back4app postgress DB.
However, when I deploy files to back4app public folder (I am not using any cloud code at the moment) - my application doesn't work and returns an error:

```
{"error":"unauthorized"}
```

I had a look at back4app logs but cannot find anything that can help me resolve the message except:

```
error: Sorry, too many clients already
```

I have a single back4app created and only one request from my phone to test whether the app will work when hosted on back4app.

Why my app is working well in local environment (I installed parse javascript sdk) and not working when deployed to back4app?

I made sure appID and jsID are correct, but that is obviously not an issue.